# overlaying tabs for translation in email

Tags: html-email

I have a simple tab structure I like for translation access. https://myally.co/l/emailTemplates/followup.php

I send the same html/css as an email and get the following:
[the tabs are not overlaid and radio buttons are not styled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thveu.png)

the same in gmail and outlook.  Hints on how to correct my html/css?  Email clients ignore absolute positioning so try this other approach?

Answer (score 0):

You ask a lot of questions and don't post your code as expected in Stack Overflow. This makes it really hard to know what you're doing and give you solutions.

Since you're asking questions and not posting samples, nobody will really help you because that's not the way this SO works.

To answer some of your questions:

- Radio buttons do not work in email.
- The JavaScript you are most likely using does not work in email.
- tabbing does not work with Outlook
- Absolute positioning does not work in email

Email development is not Web development. They use the same technologies in different ways.

For more help on what does and does not work, please visit https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/.

Good luck.